# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) > 0$

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

This is supposed to be related to the [2nd Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) (my justification for the independence tag). In Williams' Probability with Martingales, 2BCL is proven and then the following is given as an exercise:

Prove $S \doteq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) > 0$ assuming $0 \leq p_n < 1$.

Hint: Show that $S < 1 \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \geq 1 - S$.

1. I tried first to prove the hint by trying to find $\{a_n\}$ s.t.

$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \geq \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{a_n} = e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n} \geq 1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \geq 1 - S > 0$

That is, find $\{a_n\}$ s.t.:

1a. $1 - p_n \geq e^{a_n}$

1b. $a_n \leq p_n$

I thought of $a_n = \ln(1-p_n)$ (one reason why $p_n < 1$, I guess)

QED for hint

Is that right?

2. I tried next to prove the proposition:

Now if $S \geq 1$ but $S < \infty$, then $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} p_n < 1$.

Define $T \doteq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q_m = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} p_n < 1$ where $q_1 = p_k, q_2 = p_{k+1}, ...$

By hint, $T \doteq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q_m < 1 \to \prod_{m=1}^{\infty} (1-q_m) > 0 \to \prod_{n=k}^{\infty} (1 - p_n) > 0 \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - p_n) > 0$ (another reason why $p_n < 1$, I guess)

QED

Is that right?

---

From Williams book:

[image]

Comment: self-study tag?

Comment: As explained on the final lines of the above proof, $\log(1-x)\le-x$ when $0<x<1$

Comment: @Xi'an Ln(1-x) < -X < X?

Comment: [Also asked on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1433541/15941)

Comment: Because this was cross-posted and you have accepted the answer on the Math site, please post a summary of that answer here or else delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zhoraster's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1433562/140308) (link added by me):

> Hint for the case $S<1$: Prove this by induction for a finite number
>   of probabilities using that $(1-a)(1-b)\ge 1-a -b$ and then proceed to
>   the limit.
>
> Hint for the [rest of proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433567/prove-s-doteq-sum-n-1-infty-p-n-infty-to-prod-n-1-infty-1-p-n?lq=1): If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n<\infty$, then
>   there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty p_n<1$.

Expansion:

Prove by induction that $\prod_{n = 1}^{m} (1-p_n) + \sum_{n = 1}^{m} p_n \geq 1$.

Since $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty \because \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_n < 1$, we can take the limit of both sides to get

$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_n \geq 1$

and conclude that

$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \geq 1 - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_n$

Note that we can conclude that $\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \geq 0$

If $S \geq 1$, $\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \geq 1 - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_n$ is obviously true.

---

Steven Stadnicki's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433541/borel-cantelli-related-exercise-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-p-n-1-implies/1433562#comment2921008_1433562):

> Your proof looks correct at heart but it needs more additional
>   machinery than this one - you need inequalities on exp and ln, for
>   instance.